# Grab SRC Value from Inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This might be a little confusing to explain, but I've been up all night pondering it and I can't seem to get in right.

I have an Iframe running on my website, inside the iframe is **one image** with **one link**. This is what is inside of the iframe from what I grabbed out of FireBug.

```
<head>
<body style="background-color:transparent; margin:0; outline-offset:0;">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<a onclick="document.location.reload(true);" href="http://randomwebsite.com/THE-URL-I-NEED" target="_blank">
<img width="160" height="600" border="0" src="http://randomwebsite.com/RANDOM-IMAGE.JPG">
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I need to grab that single URL and set it as a variable using Jquery, then set the variable as a link outside the iframe. So I was thinking something like this.

```
<a id="myiframelink" href=""></a>
<script>$("#myiframelink").attr("href","URL-FROM-INSIDE-IFRAME");</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

if the embedded iframe url is not same as your domain, there is no way to grab that url. Otherwise, you can use something like

```
$($('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body).search("a").attr('href')
```

Comment: It's not possible at all even if the frame has fully loaded? Like this?

$("#myiframelink").attr($('#iframeid')[0].contentWindow.document.body).search("a").attr('href')